# Can any one explain java or C# implementation of Graph Data structure

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

Can any one explain java or C# implementation of  Graph Data structure (adjacency list structure -directed graph) I have a visual idea of the Graph data Structure. But if any one explains it code by code. I can understand it quickly....Can any one?

Comment: There are different types of graphs (directed/undirected, cyclic/acyclic, …) and different ways to implement each of them, so your questions is not very clear. Also, what exactly is your problem, why can't you do it yourself?

Comment: Ya u r correct ...I wanted to create a directed graph..I can do my self.But if any one give me a quick guidance,i will do it my self:)

Comment: Sure here's the cod.. oh right no, I usually get money from people who want me to solve their problems. If you want ideas? Create a node and an edge class, every node has an array of edges. Or use a 2dim boolean array with the number of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimally, you need this basic structure:

```
public class Graph{
    Set<Node> nodes;
}

public class Node{
    Set<Node> adjacent;
}
```

All that's left is constructors and accessor methods, perhaps some basic graph logic. If your algorithm requires an efficient way to find edgest directed *towards* a node, you'd have two `adjacent` sets (one with nodes the current node has an edge towards and one with nodes that have an edge towards the current one).

And if you need edge weights:

```
public class Node{
    Set<Edge> adjacent;
}

public class Edge{
    Node target;
    double weight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I got a starting point.Thanks again.